I like to close a Mesh in Blender to the floor, see attached Photos
i have some photogrammetry meshes from Drones.
(from poly.cam, so *.obj, *.dae end even Pointcloud like *.ply is possible as initial file)
I like to close all open sides to the floor.
See Photos for better understanding:


is there a solution in Blender to do this?
thanks
Flo
